# getting pixel locations in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce an html image map for a PNG produced by ggplot2.
For example:

```R
d <- data.frame(x=0:3, y=c(2,1,5,3), s=c('foo','bar','hello','world'))
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
ggsave('img.png', p, width=4, height=4, unit='in', dpi=100)
```

In this example, the first point (0,2) is roughly at pixel (65,258) and the radius is about 6 pixels, so the map I'd like my R script to generate would read like:

```html
<img src="img.png" usemap="#mymap" />
<map name="mymap">
  <area shape="circle" coords="65,258,6" href="foo.htm" alt="Foo" />
  ...
</map>
```

What's the best way to get the pixel coordinates? As mentioned in responses to other questions, ggplot2 uses a different coordinate system (grid) that base graphics, so grconvertX/Y don't work.

Comment: the function `gglocator` in package `ggmap` allows you to click on a ggplot and returns the coordinates. This is approximately what you want, so you could study the code for more inspiration.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I was hoping for less hacking... Something that would already exist & be straightforward to use...  grconvertX() and grconvertY() exist for a reason, there should be an equivalent for ggplot.